# How to get Git diff of the first commit?

Tags: git, version-control, git-diff

I created a repo, created a file inside it, put some content in the file, and committed the file. Now, I'd like to see a diff of that commit, which should ideally show the file that was added and the lines that were added to it.

However, `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` returns `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`, probably because this was the first commit to the repo.

How can this be resolved? Is there still a way to view a diff of the files that were added in the first commit?

Comment: `git show` can work. But the first diff is always from null to the whole content.

Comment: @ElpieKay That works, but that also includes the commit summary. Possible to have it print only the diff without the commit summary If I do `git show <file>`?

Comment: `git show <commit> --pretty=%% | sed 1,2d`. `%%` could be any placeholder which outputs only one line, e.g. `%h`, `%t`.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can do:

```
git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD
```

`4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` is the id of the "empty tree" in Git and it's always available in every repository.

Comment: @CharlesBaley, Cool, Where do you get this sha-1 code?

Comment: Nice, is this something documented or is this relying on shaky functionality that may go away in future?

Comment: The id of the empty tree won't change while git continues to use sha1. You can use `$(printf '' | git hash-object -t tree --stdin)` for better readability.

Comment: @gzh: I remember common sha1s.

Comment: What does this sha1 stand for?

Comment: This is hilarious to me. Why not add a named flag for this? Something like `git diff --empty-tree head`. Similar to how we have `--root` for interactive rebase.

Comment: See also [Is git's semi-secret empty tree object reliable, and why is there not a symbolic name for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765453/is-gits-semi-secret-empty-tree-object-reliable-and-why-is-there-not-a-symbolic)

Comment: @DanielWaltrip maybe this is new, but `git diff-tree` now has a `--root` option that does exactly what you were asking about.

Comment: Git supports SHA256 now, so you can't always rely on this hash id. `git init --object-format=sha256 && git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD` returns an error

Comment: @CBBailey Sadly, `git init --object-format=sha256 && git diff $(printf '' | git hash-object -t tree --stdin) HEAD` fails -- any suggestions?

Comment: git-diff does support the `--root` flag, it just isn't documented yet.

Answer (score 6):

Now that Git has experimental support for SHA256 and a [transition plan for migrating the hash function from SHA1 to SHA256](https://git-scm.com/docs/hash-function-transition/), you can no longer rely on a hash constant for the empty tree. Instead, it's best to dynamically retrieve it based on whatever hash function your repository is using:

```
git diff $(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with:

```
git log -p -n 1
```

Comment: This doesn't show the first commit. It shows the most recent one. It's not an answer to the given question.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

`git show <first-commit-sha>`

or if you only have 1 commit you can simply use:

`git show HEAD`

Comment: It doesn't show the diff.