# How to list all files added to the first commit of a GIT repository?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-diff-tree

**Current status**:
I am using `git diff-tree -r HASH` to list all added, modified and deleted files in a specific commit. This worked until today.

**The problem**:
I want to list all added files in my first commit, however passing the first HASH as a parameter doesn't work. Why?

**Main question**:
How can I get the list of all files added in my first commit?

Comment: See also [How to get Git diff of the first commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40883798/5267751)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me

```
git show <commit|branch-name> --name-only
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first commit, if you insist on `git diff-tree -r HASH`, one more parameter is needed, `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904`.

`4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` is an empty tree. In order to make this special tree object:

```
#inside your repo
git rm -r *
git write-tree
git reset HEAD --hard
```

Or a more reliable way:

```
#inside your repo
git init temp
cd temp
git commit --allow-empty -m 'empty tree'
cd ..
git fetch temp/ master
rm -rf temp
```

Now `git diff-tree -r HASH 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` works.

You can tag this tree object for easy use in the future, and push it to other repos.

```
git tag void 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
git diff-tree -r HASH void
git push <remote> void
```

Comment: You don't have to create the empty tree: it's always there. Use `git hash-object -t tree` to find its hash if you don't want to hard-code the magic number; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452.

Comment: @torek great. Thanks!

Comment: The command `git hash-object -t tree` outputs nothing in my case. According to the git man page the file is mandatory parameter so this one works for me: `git hash-object -t tree /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

`git show --pretty=format: --name-only <revision>`